# set statusbar and navigationbar color equal in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I have set navigationbar color and statusbar color to be equal but it is still visualised differently. I have set RGB color for both navigation bar and status bar.

`[UIColor colorWithRed:(61.0/255.0) green:(101.0/255.0) blue:(188.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];`

but still statusbar output different.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(61.0/255.0) green:(101.0/255.0) blue:(188.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    [delegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view]; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the code for navigationbar color ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` As the docs says:

> New behavior on iOS 7.
>    Default is YES.
>    You may force an opaque background by setting the property to NO.
>    If the navigation bar has a custom background image, the default is inferred 
>    from the alpha values of the image—YES if it has any pixel with alpha < 1.0
>    If you send setTranslucent:YES to a bar with an opaque custom background image
>    it will apply a system opacity less than 1.0 to the image.
>    If you send setTranslucent:NO to a bar with a translucent custom background image
>    it will provide an opaque background for the image using the bar's barTintColor if defined, or black
>    for UIBarStyleBlack or white for UIBarStyleDefault if barTintColor is nil.

Answer (score 0):

To change the status bar color we need to get the status bar as uiview like this

```
guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return false }
```

and then change the background color of the view

```
statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 194, green: 31, blue: 31)
```

now the status bar will look like this one in the image

[image: Statusbar with Color]

Giving navigation bar color is simple

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 32, blue: 31)
```

As a whole this will give status bar and nav bar look like this
[image: Status bar and nav bar color]